# Create a PDF Signature Field using iText7 v8.0.3

Tags: c#, itext7

I'm trying to create a PDF Signature Field on a blank PDF using iText7 version `8.0.3`

It seems that the `.CreateSignature` methods aren't there anymore, so I'm trying to figure out how do to this.

Can anyone help me out?

Here's what I was trying:

```
public async Task<FileStreamResult> DownloadPropertyList(LDSC_DownloadParams downloadParams)
{
    Instance instance = await GetInstance(downloadParams.ImplementationId);

    // Create a new PDF document
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(memoryStream);
    writer.SetCloseStream(false);
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
    Document document = new Document(pdf);

    // Create a table with a column for each property attribute
    Table table = new Table(UnitValue.CreatePercentArray(new float[] { 20, 20, 20, 10, 10, 20 }))
        .UseAllAvailableWidth();

    // Add headers to the table
    table.AddHeaderCell("Property Name");
    table.AddHeaderCell("Address");
    table.AddHeaderCell("City");
    table.AddHeaderCell("State");
    table.AddHeaderCell("Zip Code");
    table.AddHeaderCell("Contact");

    // Iterate over ScreeningProperties and add rows to the table
    foreach (var property in instance.ScreeningProperties)
    {
        table.AddCell(property.PropertyName ?? "");
        table.AddCell(property.Address ?? "");
        table.AddCell(property.City ?? "");
        table.AddCell(property.State?.ToString() ?? "");
        table.AddCell(property.ZipCode ?? "");
        table.AddCell($"{property.ContactPerson ?? ""}\n{property.PhoneNumber ?? ""}");
    }

    // Add the table to the document
    document.Add(table);

    // Add signature field
    PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, true);
    PdfFormField signature = PdfFormField.CreateSignature(pdf, new Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 50));
    signature.SetFieldName("Signature");
    form.AddField(signature);

    // Close the document
    document.Close(); // This finalizes the document and writes it to the memory stream

    // Prepare the memory stream to be returned
    memoryStream.Position = 0;

    // Return the FileStreamResult
    // Adjust the file name as needed
    return new FileStreamResult(memoryStream, "application/pdf")
    {
        FileDownloadName = "PropertyList.pdf"
    };
}
```

The issue is that `PdfFormField.CreateSignature` no longer exists in 8.0.3 and I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Got it figured out - it can be generated like this:

```
public async Task<FileStreamResult> DownloadPropertyList(LDSC_DownloadParams downloadParams)
{
    // ...

    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(memoryStream);
    writer.SetCloseStream(false);
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
    Document document = new Document(pdf);

    PdfPage page = pdf.AddNewPage();

    Table table = new Table(UnitValue.CreatePercentArray(new float[] { 20, 20, 20, 10, 10, 20 }))
        .UseAllAvailableWidth();

    Style headerStyle = new Style()
        .SetBold()
        .SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
        .SetVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE)
        .SetFontSize(10);

    Style cellStyle = new Style()
        .SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
        .SetVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE)
        .SetFontSize(7);

    String[] headers = { "Property Name", "Address", "City", "State", "Zip Code", "Contact" };
    foreach (var header in headers)
    {
        table.AddHeaderCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(header)).AddStyle(headerStyle));
    }

    foreach (var property in instance.ScreeningProperties)
    {
        table.AddCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(property.PropertyName ?? "")).AddStyle(cellStyle));
        table.AddCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(property.Address ?? "")).AddStyle(cellStyle));
        table.AddCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(property.City ?? "")).AddStyle(cellStyle));
        table.AddCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(property.State?.ToString() ?? "")).AddStyle(cellStyle));
        table.AddCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(property.ZipCode ?? "")).AddStyle(cellStyle));
        table.AddCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph($"{property.ContactPerson ?? ""}\n{property.PhoneNumber ?? ""}")).AddStyle(cellStyle));
    }

    document.Add(table);

    // Add signature field
    PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, true);
    PdfWidgetAnnotation widget = new(new Rectangle(70, 20, 150, 25));
    PdfSignatureFormField signature = new PdfFormFactory().CreateSignatureFormField(widget, pdf);
    widget.SetPage(pdf.GetLastPage());
    widget.SetVisibility(4);
    signature.SetFieldName("Signature");
    form.AddField(signature);

    // Add a label for the signature
    Paragraph signatureLabel = new Paragraph("Signature:")
        .SetFixedPosition(pdf.GetNumberOfPages(), 22, 18, 150)
        .SetFont(PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA))
        .SetFontSize(10);
    document.Add(signatureLabel);

    // Draw a line for the signature
    PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdf.GetLastPage());
    canvas
        .BeginText()
        .MoveText(70, 20)
        .SetFontAndSize(PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA), 10)
        .EndText()
        .SetLineWidth(0.5f)
        .MoveTo(70, 20)
        .LineTo(220, 20)
        .Stroke();

    document.Close();

    memoryStream.Position = 0;

    return new FileStreamResult(memoryStream, "application/pdf")
    {
        FileDownloadName = "TestGeneration.pdf"
    };
}
```

[image: Signature Screenshot]